# How to Get Global Article Parameters in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I'm programming a module in Joomla! 2.5. The module displays an article at a given position.
I need article attributes (i.e. `show_title`, `link_title` ecc.)
With this code I get article's specific attributes:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE id='.$id.' AND state=1';
$db->setQuery($query);
$item = $db->loadObject();
$attribs = json_decode($item->attribs, true);
```

If i `var_dump` the `$attribs` variable I get:

```
array(26) {
  ["show_title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["link_titles"]=>
  string(0) ""

  [...]

}
```

The variable `$attribs` represents the article's specific attributes. When an element is set to `""` means "use the global configuration".

I can get the global configuration with this query:

```
SELECT params from #__extensions where extension_id=22;
```

Where 22 is the id of the `com_component` extension. Then I can merge the results here with the results for the specific article.

**BUT** is there an easy way to achieve this? Does Joomla! have a specific class in the framework for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with loading the model for articles:

```
// Get an instance of the generic articles model
$model = JModel::getInstance('Article',
                             'ContentModel',
                             array('ignore_request' => true));
```

The get the specific article...

```
$model->getItem($id)
```

To get a components global params I believe you can use:

```
$params = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'COMPONENT_NAME' );
```

In your case you would need something like:

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper'); // load component helper first
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content');
```

I would suggest you look at the code of the article modules that ship with Joomla! 2.5.x as they do a lot of similar things to what you're trying to create. You can also have a read of [this article](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_parameters), it's a bit dated but I think it still mostly holds true (except for jparams being replaced by jforms).

Comment: Before `$model->getItem($id);` you have to set `JModel`'s parameters. This took me a while. Here's the code:
`$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);`.
Without that you an error occours.